# How to run tensorflow model on Coral CPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral

Is it possible at all to run Tensorflow model not on `Edge-TPU` but on Coral's `CPU`?
Is it possible to build Tensorflow for Mendel OS?

I have the model that couldn't be converted by `edge` compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any model that is not Edge TPU compatible will run on the CPU by default. From the [TensorFlow on Edge TPU >Model Requirements](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/)  docs:

> If your model does not meet these requirements entirely, it can still compile, but only a portion of the model will execute on the Edge TPU. At the first point in the model graph where an unsupported operation occurs, the compiler partitions the graph into two parts. The first part of the graph that contains only supported operations is compiled into a custom operation that executes on the Edge TPU, and everything else executes on the CPU

Were you able to convert your model to TFLite?

Comment: My model is not quantized so the TPU compiler is throwing me an error. I wanted instead to run my model using vanilla tensorflow, but compiling it for tensorflow is possibly trickier than just training the model using quantization-aware training.

Comment: You'll need to go through the quantization step for your model. If you just want to run it on CPU, then no need to pass it through a compiler at all.